# view push.default value in git

Tags: git

I have GIT **2.11** version. I have read `push.default`  default value is `simple`. When I do `git config --list` I don't see any `push.default` there. Why ? How can I see this value ? Does that mean it is unset ? I installed GIT in mac os sierra.

Comment: I sometimes refer to these as *default defaults:* a *default* is what something sets if you don't override it, but in this case a *default default* is what you get if you don't *set* it either! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push.default` default value is `simple`. That is if not overridden in config it is assumed by `git` to be `simple`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault

Answer (score 1):

The results from `git config --list` will depend on your current repository. It returns the values from the system, global and repository local configuration.

You can view the all config values and where they're set using:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

If you don't see it, then it hasn't been configured and you're using the default value.

Comment: But does git not promises it will set the `push.default` as simple ? By the way , I still see nothing.

Comment: I don't see anything either. It doesn't seem to list all defaults.

Comment: So is it set or unset ?

Comment: Without explcit value(s) in your configs it's *assumed* to be `simple`. I.e. it's always set but you can override it.

Comment: @phd Please post as answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.